# Canvas Path2d inner shadow

Tags: canvas, svg, shadow

I create svg and i wanna convert svg to canvas.
I do the following:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var p = new Path2D("M10 10 h 80 v 80 h -80 Z");
ctx.fillStyle = '#cb1a2f';
ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
ctx.shadowBlur = 24;
ctx.fill(p);
```

But I want to make the shadow inside the square. I have a completely different figure SVG. this SVG is purely an example.

Comment: @Kaiido it only moves a shadow, and I need to place it inside the shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shadows are both inside and outside of the shape in canvas API :

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
ctx.shadowColor = "black";
ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
ctx.strokeRect(20,20,50,50);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

But fill and stroke are rendered on top of this shadow.

So what you could do, is to first fill your shape, then set the context's [`globalCompositeOperation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) property to `source-atop` so that new drawings are kept only where we already have drawn something, and finally call a stroke of your path.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var p = new Path2D("M10 10 h 80 v 80 h -80 Z");
ctx.fillStyle = ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
// fill a first time
ctx.fill(p);
// change the gCO
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
ctx.shadowColor = "green";
ctx.shadowBlur = 14;
// now stroke to get the inner shadow
ctx.stroke(p);

// reset the gCO to its default
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```